# jquerymobile fieldcontain adjust width

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using fieldcontain with form elements in my jquery mobile app. This works well, but I have some fields that have fairly long labels, often combined with an input that could be very short. The label is wrapping to 3 or 4 lines of text, while the input is taking up the rest of the width. The problem is the input could be quite short for some of these, so it seems a waste that the label be smashed up to give the input box a bunch of room it doesnt even need.

I'd like to know if I could per-line alter the 78% width that is assigned to the input box, perhaps making it 40% and allow the label to expand out further? Are there best practices for this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Layout Grid which will get you 50% / 50% without any effort.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

It looks like the 1.3 responsive grids will allow for some manipulation for column widths

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/content/content-grids-responsive.html

Comment: will this retain the filedcontain feature that when the screen is too narrow, it will put the label above the input? thanks